# Log monitoring Zabbix

Tags: logging, time, monitoring, zabbix

I want o monitor a log file and fire an alert only if I receive `error` more than 9 times in last 5 minutes, and if I don't get any error in the last 5 minutes set It to OK State.

see below trigger.

```
{Zabbix server:log["/opt/test.log","ERROR",,300].count(5m,"ERROR")}>9
```

Above Trigger will fire trigger. but its not coming back to OK State if I don't receive `error` in log file.

How to get Notified for `OK STATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below trigger for the above requirements, it will definitely solve your problem for what you are looking.

```
{Zabbix Agent:log[/home/abhishek/Desktop/zabbix_scripts/test.log,**Error**].count(5m,"Error")}>9 and {Zabbix Agent:log[/home/abhishek/Desktop/zabbix_scripts/test.log,**Error**].nodata(5m)}=0
```

Also change keywords according to your needs.